# Placing integers in specific spots in an array in MIPS assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

```
array1: alloc 10          //allocate an array of size 10
array2: alloc 10          //allocate an array of size 10
```

How would I put say a value of 40 in the 1st spot of array1 ( array1[0] ) and a value of 28 in the third spot of array2 ( array2[2] )?

This is being created as MIPS assembly; I am thinking it is something like

```
addi $2, $0, 40
swi $2, array1($0)
```

but I'm not sure how to put it in a specific spot in the array.

Comment: Offset the address as required. Note that words are 4 bytes each. It's unclear what your `alloc` does, make sure it uses the appropriate data type. You might do something like `sw $2, array1+4`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where the array is allocated.  Let's assume it is a global array.  Then the usual approach would be to load the address of the array into a register, say `$t1` as follows:

```
la $t1, array1   # assemble the address of array1 into register $t1
```

This will generate a (two instruction sequence) to put the address of `array1` into the `$t1` register.  Next, you can store into that location as follows:

```
sw $t2, 0($t1)     # here let's say $t2 holds your value 40
```

If you wanted to store into the 3rd element of `array1`, then that is 3*4 bytes further down so you'd use:

```
sw $t2, 12($t1)
```

You can see that what you'd need to change to access the 3rd of `array2` instead of `array1` is that you'd use an `la` for `array2` (perhaps to a different register).

Of course, there are also other ways this can be done; however, this approach of loading the address of the array into a register offers flexibility for further operations on the array.

If you didn't know the index position, i.e. you wanted the `i`th position (instead of a constant like 3rd position), then we would do an indexing computation.  We'd still start with the `la` to get the base address of the global array into a register (if we didn't have it already available).

We would also compute `i` * sizeof (element of the array), which in this case is 4, so (and let's assume here `i` is in `$a0`):

```
sll $t3, $a0, 2    # to multiply by 4 we shift left by 2 bit positions
```

and the sum that together with the base array address:

```
add $t3, $t1, $t3
```

so now we can store using $t3 as the base register: `$t3` holds `array1 + i * 4`

```
sw $t2, 0($t3)
```